# How to modify the position of an Image object?

Tags: gwt

In GWT, how do you set the position of an Image object after it was added to a Panel? There does not seem to be a method to set the Image top and left positions. Do we have to remove the image from the Panel and add it again using the desired left and top values? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was simply:

```
absolutePanel.setWidgetPosition(myImage, newXvalue, newYvalue);
```

Assuming that 'myImage' was a child of absolutePanel.

Answer (score 2):

If you set absolute positions, you can

```
int top = myPanel.getAbsoluteTop();
int left = myPanel.getAbsoluteLeft();
myImage.getElement().getStyle().setTop(top + 100, Unit.PX);
myImage.getElement().getStyle().setLeft(left + 100, Unit.PX);
```

Alternatively, you can set "position: relative" style on your image. Then you can set "top" and "left" on an image, and it would position itself relative to its parent element.

Comment: My Image object is inside a Panel. I need to set the Image position relative to this panel.

Comment: I updated my answer, but you need to edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

From the way your questions is asked, I assume that you are trying to use GWT as you would use Swing or SWT from Java. This is not the way GWT is ment to used and leads to very bad code and very bad projects most of the time.

GWT is not about hiding the browser. So if you want to change the postion of an element you would do that mostly with CSS.

Simply add two css classes to your project

```
.before{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.after{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

at first give your image the first class:

```
image.addStyleName("before");
```

and later:

```
image.addStyleName("after");
```

If you really need to make this dynamically (some calculated size) you can just set the style property of the element:

```
image.getElement().getStyle().setLeft(value, Unit.PX); 
image.getElement().getStyle().setTop(value, Unit.PX);
```

Comment: Yes I need it to be dynamic, I am moving the Image object based on a changing value.